Entry page with infinite scroll and push url for the next one
What I'm trying to do is to make something like this:
https://www.lrytas.lt/verslas/rinkos-pulsas/2024/10/21/news/sanso-jav-atsisakiusio-ir-pas-v-romanova-likusio-verslininko-byloje-pikantiskos-istorijos-misles-ir-nemenka-suma-34682549
So you read one entry and then get another one after with url being pushed to the browser. Any ideas how to achieve something like this on Craft?

I’m voting to close this question because it's not a Craft related question. This is 'how do I implement infinite scroll'.
